# CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName and dlsym return NULL for exported function

Tags: ios, frameworks, nsbundle, dlopen, dlsym

I have a fork of the JavaScriptCore framework, where I have added a function of my own, which is exported. The framework compiles just find. Running `nm` on the framework reveals that the function (`JSContextCreateBacktrace_unsafe`) is indeed exported:

```
Leo-Natans-Wix-MPB:JavaScriptCore.framework lnatan$ nm -gU JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore | grep JSContextCreateBacktrace
00000000004cb860 T _JSContextCreateBacktrace
00000000004cba10 T _JSContextCreateBacktrace_unsafe
```

However, I am unable to obtain the pointer of that function using `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName` or `dlsym`; both return `NULL`. At first, I used `dlopen` to open my framework, then tried using `CFBundleCreate` and then `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName` but that also returns NULL.

What could cause this?

**Update**

Something fishy is going on. I renamed one of the JSC functions, and `nm` reflects this. However, `dlsym` is still able to find the function with the original name, rather than the renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to track this down since it's highly dependent on your specific environment and circumstances, but it is very likely you're running into this issue because the system image has already been loaded and you haven't changed the name of the framework.

If you look at the source code for `dlopen` in [dyld/dyldAPIS.cpp:1458](https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/195030646877261f0c8c7ad8b001f52d6a26f514/src/dyldAPIs.cpp#L1458-L1471), you'll notice the context passed to dyld is configured with `matchByInstallName = true`. This context is then passed to `load` which executes the various stages necessary for image loading. There are a few phases worth noting:

- `loadPhase2` in [dyld/dyld.cpp:2896](https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/195030646877261f0c8c7ad8b001f52d6a26f514/src/dyld.cpp#L2896) extracts the ending of the framework path and searches for it in the search path
- `loadPhase5check` in [dyld/dyld:2712](https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/195030646877261f0c8c7ad8b001f52d6a26f514/src/dyld.cpp#L2712-L2731) iterates over all loaded images and determines if any of them have a matching install name, and if one does, it returns that instead of loading a new one.
- `loadPhase5load` in [dyld/dyld:2601](https://github.com/opensource-apple/dyld/blob/195030646877261f0c8c7ad8b001f52d6a26f514/src/dyld.cpp#L2601) finally loads the image if it wasn't loaded/found by any earlier steps. (It's worth noting `loadPhase5check` is executed first, since image loading is a two pass process.)

Given all of the above, I'd try renaming your framework to something besides `JavaScriptCore.framework`. Depending on the install name of both the system framework and your framework, I'd also recommend changing the install name. (There are plenty of blog articles and StackOverflow posts that document how to do this using `install_name_tool -id`.)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you for the well sourced answer!